# Why is my camera preview not respecting the layout?

Tags: android, camera

I'm creating a SurfaceView for my camera preview and attempting to have it occupy a rectangle that's smaller than the entire screen, but it's ignoring my layout command.

I assume I'm doing something wrong, but can't find an example of someone setting the preview into a smaller container.

All advice (or pointers to examples) appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's how it's done in the default Camera application: [layout file](http://android.git.kernel.org/?p=platform/packages/apps/Camera.git;a=blob;f=res/layout/camera.xml;h=772106bfde89309d5137fa2cf4fa476d7991c176;hb=HEAD) and [source code](http://android.git.kernel.org/?p=platform/packages/apps/Camera.git;a=blob;f=src/com/android/camera/PreviewFrameLayout.java;h=1ec629fd3f38d30306be308d040f937b09c24b4f;hb=HEAD).

There's a container that performs a special layout procedure depending on a given aspect ratio. I think you can adapt this solution to your needs.

Comment: ah... not entirely obvious, but I figured it out with enough noodling